# Determine the coefficient of variation of $10X – 5Y$.

Tags: probability

Let X denote the outcome of the roll of a four-faced ordinary die, and let Y denote the outcome of the roll of a six-faced ordinary die. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Determine the coefficient of variation of $10X – 5Y.$

Prepare for a long winded one, here's the full attempt

Possible outcomes of the rolls:

$(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6)
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6)
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6)
(4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5) (4,6)$

So here goes,

$$E(X)=-20P(X=1,Y=6)-15P(X=1,Y=5)-10(P(X=1,Y=4)+P(X=2,Y=6))-5(P(X=1,Y=3)+P(X=2,Y=5))+0((P(X=1,Y=2)+P(X=2,Y=4)+P(X=3,Y=6))+5(P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=2,Y=3)+P(X=3,Y=5))+10(P(X=2,Y=2)+P(X=3,Y=4)+P(X=4,Y=6))+15(P(X=2,Y=1)+(P(X=3,Y=3)+P(X=4,Y=5))+20P(X=3,Y=2)+25(P(X=3,Y=1)+P(X=4,Y=3))+30P(X=4,Y=2)+35P(X=4,Y=2)$$

Now this monstrosity simplifies, if I did it right as I believe $P(X=x,Y=y)={1\over6}^2$ so we end up with $$E(X)={-20\over 36}+{-15\over 36}+{-10\over 18}+{-5\over 18}+{0\over 12}+{5\over 12}+{10\over 12}+{25\over 18}+{30\over 36}+{35\over 36}$$ Now I computed $Var(X)$ similarly to get $\sigma_x$ then did $\sigma_x\over\mu_x$ but did not get an answer that is an option.

Comment: What is the "right" answer that is given?

Comment: @Max Haven't a clue, options are $0.178, 0.272, 0.960, 1.876 \text{ or } 14.068$

Comment: @Heavenly96 Is the answer 0.960?

Comment: @Brenton, I'm not sure. I won't know until I submit the practice exam. How did you get .96?

Comment: You should always include the given answers.

Comment: @Heavenly96 Ignore me, I believe I made a small calculation error (I wrote $10^2\operatorname{Var}(X)+5^2\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ with a minus sign instead of a plus sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z = 10X-5Y$. I've never heard of a "coefficient of variation", but according to Wikipedia, I believe it should be $\frac{\operatorname{SD}(Z)}{E[Z]}$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(Z) &= \operatorname{Var}(10X-5Y) \\
&= 10^2\operatorname{Var}(X)+5^2\operatorname{Var}(Y) \\
&= 100\cdot\frac{(4-1+1)^2-1}{12}+25\cdot\frac{(6-1+1)^2-1}{12}\\
&=\frac{2375}{12}
\end{align*}

where the variance of a discrete uniform random variable on $[a,\dotsc, b]$ is well-known to be $\frac{(b-a+1)^2-1}{12}$.

Then
$$E[Z] = 10E[X]-5E[Y] = 10\cdot\frac{1+4}{2}-5\cdot\frac{1+6}{2} = \frac{15}{2}$$
since the expectation of a discrete random variable on $[a,\dotsc, b]$ is well known to be $\frac{a+b}{2}$. Finally
$$\frac{\operatorname{SD}(Z)}{E[Z]} = \frac{\sqrt{2375/12}}{15/2}\approx 1.875771.$$

which rounds to $1.876$, one of the given options.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I can't say I've seen a discrete uniform before.

Comment: Are you taking a statistics class or a probability class? If you are, you should become familiar with it because it is a basic/required topic.

Comment: I am self teaching myself probability currently in preparation for taking the P exam eventually. I graduated with a bachelors in math but never took any probability or stats courses